# How do I use the data from the Twitter API in jQuery?

Tags: json, jquery, post

I would like to use the data you get when calling the following URL from my browser: https://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids.json?cursor=-1&user_id=92558104

My question is: how can I make the same action with jQuery (something like a post-request maybe?) and catch the received data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`$.getJSON`](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9AGG/1/) to do so.

Like:

```
$.getJSON('https://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids.json?cursor=-1&user_id=92558104&callback=?',function(data){
console.log(data);
});​
```

The success handler function specified in the `$.getJSON` call receives a `data` argument that will contain the data returned by your request. See **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9AGG/1/)**. In case you need error handling you can (should) also add another function for that.

Be aware that you need to make sure you are using **[JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)** here as this will probably be a cross-domain-request. This can be done adding a plain `&callback=?` to the URL your are calling. See the **[twitter docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search)** for info on that.

Answer (score 1):

you can not call this directly from javascript because it's on a different domain, the easiest thing to do is to call it from the server side and then pass it to your browser.

The better solution would be to use the twitter api to make JSONP callbacks

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search

Comment: Tnanks dude...thats the answer I needed!